# How to align multiple icons with text vertically in CSS?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

> I have a following div with some icons and texts (Map lengends) as
>   below:

[image]

**HTML code for the above:**

```
<div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_layer5_0_legend0">
    <div style="padding-left: 36px;">
        <span class="agsjsTOCContent">      
        <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 20px; width:20px;">
     <span></span>
        <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 01</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for the above**

```
.agsjsTOCNode {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    direction: rtl;
    }
    .agsjsTOCContent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.agsjsTOCIcon {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.agsjsTOCLegendLabel {
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

> My target is to align multiple icons with text vertically in CSS as
>   below:

[image]

**Please see the jsfiddle:** 
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/aaziz/a1reyktv/16/)

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 3):

If you can update your HTML structure to wrap the img element, here is a flex-based solution:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.agsjsTOCNode {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    direction: rtl;
}

.agsjsTOCContent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.agsjsTOCIconContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.agsjsTOCLegendLabel {
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_layer5_0_legend0">
    <div style="padding-left: 36px;">
      <span class="agsjsTOCContent">
        <span class="agsjsTOCIconContainer">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 20px; width:20px;">
        </span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 01</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_layer5_0_legend1">
    <div style="padding-left: 36px;">
      <span class="agsjsTOCContent">
        <span class="agsjsTOCIconContainer">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 25px; width:25px;">
        </span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 02</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_layer5_0_legend2">
    <div style="padding-left: 36px;">
      <span class="agsjsTOCContent">
        <span class="agsjsTOCIconContainer">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 30px; width:30px;">
        </span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 03</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_layer5_0_legend3">
    <div style="padding-left: 36px;">
      <span class="agsjsTOCContent">
        <span class="agsjsTOCIconContainer">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 35px; width:35px;">
        </span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 04</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_layer5_0_legend4">
    <div style="padding-left: 36px;">
      <span class="agsjsTOCContent">
        <span class="agsjsTOCIconContainer">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 40px; width:40px;">
        </span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 05</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_layer5_0_legend5">
    <div style="padding-left: 36px;">
      <span class="agsjsTOCContent">
        <span class="agsjsTOCIconContainer">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 45px; width:45px;">
        </span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 06</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try flex or grid layout,

```
parent{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

This way any icon you use BIgger than text or smaller , the pair will be aligned every time.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/

Try some research before posting for help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did align the text with the icon for individual set (icon+text). But what about aliging vertically each set?

Comment: Give that rule to parent that wraps all sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex.

```css
.agsjsTOCNode {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    direction: rtl;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    }
    .agsjsTOCContent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.agsjsTOCIcon {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.agsjsTOCLegendLabel {
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="agsjsTOCNode">
   <span class="agsjsTOCContent">      
 <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png" alt="" class="agsjsTOCIcon" style="height: 20px; width:20px;">
   </span>
   <span class="agsjsTOCLegendLabel">Legend 01 <br>Legend 02<br>Legend 03</span>
 </div>
```

thats all

Answer (score 0):

Just change your style for icon to this:

```
.agsjsTOCIcon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately still the same

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Is it not the desired output you have mentioned in the question? If no, please add more info.

Comment: It did align the text with the icon for individual set (icon+text). But what about aliging vertically each set?

Comment: How do u want  ? @AbdulAziz , Can u send photo ?

Comment: Kindly check the 2nd image in my original question. thanks for bearing with me guys.

Comment: Okay, I think I may have got it. You want the legends and icons to be align justified and icons next to them.